# Почему не отображается SVG, добавленное с помощью тега <img>

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Это код svg-ки, у меня она названа как 3.svg.

```html
<svg width="16" height="20" viewBox="0 0 16 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<rect width="16" height="20" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0" transform="scale(0.0625 0.05)"/>
</pattern>
<image id="image0" width="16" height="20" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAUCAIAAAALACogAAABJklEQVQokZXSwYqDMBAG4Lz/G4giBEp6E0ukKPWQEAlCe5KIuUh7KBQED54kQpgedLfutrruf/6/kGEGAQAAWGubpimKQggRBAEhZL/fx3Gc53lVVW3bwlcQAGitMcbOana73fV6nQDnfL095nK5TGAYhsPhsN4+nU7W2gkAQNd168AY85phTJIkS20p5Y+hx1BKlwDn/AOQUi6Boig+gLZtPc97b2OM+77/AMaFuK47b/u+f7vd5p0JKKWOx2OWZY/HgzEWBEEYhkKIpmnSNE2SpK7rF8jz/PtJQoiUsixLpVSWZfMLUEoBAPpzA/PvGWPQ+XzeCBzH0VqjOI63A8YYIoRsB5TS/4MoirYDzjmqqmo7uN/vaBiGNE1/Lfg9nucJIay1TxFRp7e6u6JTAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"/>
</defs>
</svg>
```

так ее вставляю в html страницу.

```html
<img src="3.svg"/>
```

Если вставлять код svg, то все отображается, а если другим способом, то что-то не хочет, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Это не **svg** изображение. Данное изображение получается **png**.

Comment: Все работает. Может путь неправильно прописан?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Лучше не брать svg изображения формата `base64` по многим причинам:

- Это не 100% svg, а формат png обернутый в оболочку svg, поэтому не
  будет адаптивности, которую ожидаем от формата SVG
- Изображение не будет стилизоваться (менять цвет)
- Посмотрите, как выглядит ваша иконка при небольшом увеличении

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проще скачать нужную иконку в формате svg с любого [векторного клипарта](https://openclipart.org/search/?query=user)

Я взял иконку [**user**](https://openclipart.org/detail/287798/user)

На первых порах освоения svg добавляйте иконки инлайн, то есть непосредственным копированием кода в HTML

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" viewBox="0 0 248 248" version="1.1">
<g id="icon" transform="translate(0,-804.33071)">
<path d="m76.4 1042.7c-2.2-0.2-4.7-0.7-5.6-1-0.8-0.3-9.3-2.9-18.9-5.6-9.6-2.8-17.5-5.1-17.5-5.2-0.2-0.2 2.3-42.5 2.9-48.1 2.3-21.6 6-32.2 14.9-41.6 7.6-8.1 14.9-11.8 27.5-13.7 5.5-0.9 39.4-1.2 47.6-0.5 13 1.1 21.3 3.1 29.1 6.9 3.9 1.9 5.5 3.1 9.1 6.7 9.4 9.4 13.8 22.4 15.9 47.4 1.2 14 2.5 42.6 2 43.1-0.9 0.9-17.7 5.6-23.4 6.5-20.4 3.4-70.3 6.5-83.6 5.1z" />
<ellipse cx="107" cy="883.1" rx="40.7" ry="38.3" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Теперь легко применить стили из внешней css, к нашей иконке, например при наведении.
(не забудьте удалить стили внутри svg, чтобы они не мешали)

```css
#icon {
fill:black;
stroke:black;
transition: .5s ease-out all;
}
#icon:hover {
fill:skyblue;
stroke:dodgerblue;

}
```

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" viewBox="0 0 248 248" version="1.1">
<g id="icon" transform="translate(0,-804.33071)">
<path d="m76.4 1042.7c-2.2-0.2-4.7-0.7-5.6-1-0.8-0.3-9.3-2.9-18.9-5.6-9.6-2.8-17.5-5.1-17.5-5.2-0.2-0.2 2.3-42.5 2.9-48.1 2.3-21.6 6-32.2 14.9-41.6 7.6-8.1 14.9-11.8 27.5-13.7 5.5-0.9 39.4-1.2 47.6-0.5 13 1.1 21.3 3.1 29.1 6.9 3.9 1.9 5.5 3.1 9.1 6.7 9.4 9.4 13.8 22.4 15.9 47.4 1.2 14 2.5 42.6 2 43.1-0.9 0.9-17.7 5.6-23.4 6.5-20.4 3.4-70.3 6.5-83.6 5.1z" />
<ellipse cx="107" cy="883.1" rx="40.7" ry="38.3" />
</g>
</svg>
```

### Чтобы сделать иконку адаптивной

Необходимо убрать `width="70"`,  `height="70"` из шапки svg файла. Обернуть иконку в контейнер  и задать в процентах ширину и высоту контейнера

```css
.container {
width:10%;
height:10%;
}
#icon {
fill:black;
stroke:black;
transition: .5s ease-out all;
}
#icon:hover {
fill:skyblue;
stroke:dodgerblue;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 248 248" version="1.1">
<g id="icon" transform="translate(0,-804.33071)">
<path d="m76.4 1042.7c-2.2-0.2-4.7-0.7-5.6-1-0.8-0.3-9.3-2.9-18.9-5.6-9.6-2.8-17.5-5.1-17.5-5.2-0.2-0.2 2.3-42.5 2.9-48.1 2.3-21.6 6-32.2 14.9-41.6 7.6-8.1 14.9-11.8 27.5-13.7 5.5-0.9 39.4-1.2 47.6-0.5 13 1.1 21.3 3.1 29.1 6.9 3.9 1.9 5.5 3.1 9.1 6.7 9.4 9.4 13.8 22.4 15.9 47.4 1.2 14 2.5 42.6 2 43.1-0.9 0.9-17.7 5.6-23.4 6.5-20.4 3.4-70.3 6.5-83.6 5.1z" />
<ellipse cx="107" cy="883.1" rx="40.7" ry="38.3" />
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, с помощью вашего ответа разобралась в своей проблеме!

Comment: @Настя Силаева  Да не за что/ Ответ так долго ждал вас :) Заглядывайте почаще и задавайте вопросы